# Project not recognizing custom framework despite

Tags: swift, module, frameworks

I have a workspace that uses CocoaPods for remote frameworks and also has custom frameworks that are not managed by CocoaPods, but that reference other libraries managed by CocoaPods.

My project has targets for the product as well as its custom frameworks. On all targets, $(PROJECT_DIR) is included as one of the framework search paths with recursive set to true. Always Search User Paths is set to Yes for the product and custom frameworks. Always Embed Standard Swift Libraries is set to Yes only for the product. Defines Module and Enable Clang Module Debugging are set to yes for all relevant targets. And every umbrella header file of each custom framework is included in the relevant custom framework as a public header.

Despite all this, when a Swift file in of the custom frameworks imports one of the other custom frameworks, it results in a 'No such module' compiler error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you add some specifics? Something we can try to duplicate? Obviously the issue is with dependancies - and when using Pods along with other custom frameworks - not to mention multiple targets - things can get dicey. (1) These are build errors, right? (2) Can you provide some code (minimally as possible) to duplicate? (3) Third party frameworks that `import` other third party frameworks can have issues... obviously! This includes *your* frameworks. So can you post enough specifics to have another dev duplicate it?

Comment: I'd provide module names, but because I'm currently working at a stealth mode startup and the modules have the company's name in them, I can't.

And yes, they are build errors.

I can, however, list the pods that are used:

GoogleSignIn
GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive
FMDB
DropDown
SocketRocket
CocoaAsyncSocket
XLPagerTabStrip
CoreStore
XLPagerTabStrip
AFNetworking
SVProgressHUD
Fabric
Crashlytics

The aforementioned pods are separate from the custom frameworks within the project.